# Postman passing raw json data in an array

Tags: arrays, postman, webhooks

I currently have a URI - http://example.com/restful_api/photo?access-token=xxx

```
Parameters: 

image[]: array

val[description]:string
```

Testing it out with PostMan Form Data it works perfectly. However, it doesn’t work with raw data json.

I have tried the following raw json code as well but it’s not working:

```
Content-Type: application/json

{

"image": {["https://bucket-1.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/file/pic/photo/2020/09/b62bde83d011b33f49eca46b1c44ba03_1024.jpg"]},

"val": {"description":"here's the image"}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the API expect, form data or JSON?

Comment: @Phil - it seems like the API expects form data